# Can't do the barplot in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

I just learned R and have a question recently.

The result for `dput(head(Refugees_demographics, 20))`

```
structure(list(Year = c(2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 
2015, 2016), `Country / territory of asylum/residence` = c("Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada", 
"Mexico", "United States of America", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada"
), `Location Name` = c("Mexico City", "Mexico City", "Mexico City", 
"Canada", "Mexico City", "Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Mexico City : Point", "Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Mexico City : Point", "Mexico : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", "Mexico : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", "Mexico : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", "Mexico : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"United States of America : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Canada : Dispersed in the country / territory", "Mexico : Dispersed in the country / territory", 
"Canada"), `Female 0-4` = c(0, 3, 21, 2459, 16, 1823, 10, 2599, 
10, 0, 1408, 26, 1051, 27, 876, 20, 0, 886, 0, 316), `Female 5-11` = c(0, 
0, 38, 2882, 38, 2305, 26, 4344, 26, 0, 1948, 53, 1818, 61, 1193, 
43, 0, 897, 0, 477), `Female 12-17` = c(140, 36, 68, 2012, 69, 
1735, 71, 3543, 64, 0, 1465, 89, 1342, 102, 828, 75, 0, 603, 
0, 443), `Female 18-59` = c(1118, 519, 246, 18745, 303, 15421, 
386, 26419, 345, 0, 13677, 401, 10426, 511, 7842, 380, 0, 5301, 
0, 7234), `Female 60+` = c(121, 85, 32, 1095, 43, 1026, 28, 2069, 
28, 0, 1065, 8, 845, 6, 742, 4, 0, 358, 0, 514), `F: Total` = c(1379, 
643, 405, 27193, 469, 22310, 521, 38974, 473, 0, 19563, 577, 
15482, 707, 11481, 522, 0, 8045, 0, 8984), `Male 0-4` = c(0, 
7, 4, 2513, 8, 1899, 9, 2615, 8, 0, 1447, 16, 1031, 23, 838, 
14, 0, 946, 0, 469), `Male 5-11` = c(6, 1, 22, 3020, 29, 2445, 
25, 4459, 24, 0, 1966, 40, 1785, 60, 1258, 39, 0, 914, 0, 471
), `Male 12-17` = c(152, 56, 106, 2137, 116, 1819, 85, 3686, 
83, 0, 1605, 80, 1511, 94, 956, 66, 0, 665, 0, 512), `Male 18-59` = c(1323, 
870, 500, 25620, 636, 21944, 884, 31700, 764, 0, 17773, 734, 
13297, 945, 10678, 652, 0, 7666, 0, 12969), `Male 60+` = c(595, 
88, 36, 669, 73, 608, 43, 1253, 43, 0, 583, NA, 550, 2, 447, 
2, 0, 257, 0, 526), `M: Total` = c(2076, 1022, 668, 33959, 862, 
28715, 1046, 43713, 922, 0, 23374, 870, 18174, 1124, 14177, 773, 
0, 10448, 0, 14947)), .Names = c("Year", "Country / territory of asylum/residence", 
"Location Name", "Female 0-4", "Female 5-11", "Female 12-17", 
"Female 18-59", "Female 60+", "F: Total", "Male 0-4", "Male 5-11", 
"Male 12-17", "Male 18-59", "Male 60+", "M: Total"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`
```

I have a data frame below. This is a subset from a original dataset. I use the following code to create this:

```
aggregate(Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4` ~ 
           Year,data=Refugees_demographics ,FUN="sum")
```

- Year                  Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4` 
     2006                                            0 
     2007                                           3 
     2008                                          21 
     2009                                     2475 
     2010                                      1833 
     2011                                     2609 
     2012                                   1434 
     2013                                   1078 
     2014                                      896 
     2015                                     886 
     2016                                    316

I tried to draw a barplot. However, it keep getting error message like "Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator. " Then I tried to convert it from character to numeric but it's not work. Could you have me to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Does your data frame have the column name `Refugees_demographics$Female 0-4 `? And can you post code that you have tried?

Comment: It appears that the problem is with `Refugees_demographics`,  but we will need to see what it looks like to help.  Please type `dput(Refugees_demographics)` and paste the answer into your question.  If there is too much data, you can use `dput(head(Refugees_demographics, 20))`

Comment: Hi @G5W,

Thanks for the response. Please see the result for dput(head(Refugees_demographics,20))  in the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barplot` is working for me.

```
TAB = aggregate(`Female 0-4` ~ Year, data=Refugees_demographics, FUN="sum")
barplot(TAB$`Female 0-4`, names.arg=TAB$Year)
```

[image: Barplot]

You may need to stretch the graphics window out to get all of the labels to show.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works now. 

My first try is:

Total <- aggregate(Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4` ~ Year,data=Refugees_demographics ,FUN="sum")

barplot(total$Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4`)

And I get the following error message:

Error in total$Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4` : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: I think that you need to remove the `Refugees_demographics` part in your barplot  ``barplot(Total$`Female 0-4)` ``  Also, be careful. R is case sensitive.  `Total` is not the same as `total`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ggplot2`?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(your_data) + geom_bar( aes(x = year, y = your_variable)
```

Comment: It shows other error message :

Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'any'